# Activator.Createinstance leads to target invocation

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method like this:

```
    private void StartTask<T>(string car, string connectionId, string something)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (T), car, connectionId, something))
            .ContinueWith(
                task =>
                {
                    if (task.Exception != null)
                        new LoggerService(GetType()).Exception(task.Exception);
                },
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    }
```

As you can see, I need to use Activator.CreateInstance to create an instance of the class passed into the generic method.

I am calling this method like this:

```
            StartTask<CarClass1>("Volvo", "4", "something");
            StartTask<CarClass2>("Honda", "3", "something");
            StartTask<CarClass3>("Nissan", "5", "something");
```

IIS crashes **sometimes**. Using "Debug Diagnostics" I found out I get:

**Exception:**  {"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."}   System.Exception {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException}

**Inner exception:**
    {"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."}  System.Exception {System.AccessViolationException}

**Stacktrace:** The runtime has refused to evaluate the expression at this time.    string

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure the exception is raised from your code snippets?

Comment: Can you post code which can reproduce the issue?

Comment: The exception is raised here: "> ProjectMVC.dll!ProjectMVC.Hubs.StartTask<ProjectMVC.SocketClasses.Car.CarClass1>.AnonymousMethod__1() Line 55 C#"

Comment: I'm having difficulties reproducing it myself. It only seems to happen sometimes :(